# Python Script not Accurately Outputting to Console

Tags: python, java, console

I currently am creating a script to grade a file called Hangman.java. The Java file asks users to guess letters using the console. Usually, users would just enter their guess in console and everything works normally. I have created a Python file that mimics a user by using an input file (containing all the guesses separated by a new line). Currently, the Python file successfully redirects the input from the input file to the Java file and successfully saves the output from the Java file (need the output to check if it matches solution output). However, where the user (the Python script) is "entering" a guess, the output from the Java file is blank. For example,

Actual:

Enter your next guess:

You guessed T.

Expected:

Enter your next guess: T

You guessed T.

Notice, how in the expected the T is "entered" whereas in the actual script the T is simply fed in and hence is not showing in the output.

Here is my scriptL

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def run_java_with_input(java_file, input_file, output_file):
    subprocess.run(['javac', java_file + '.java'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_file), exist_ok=True)
    with open(input_file, 'r') as inputs, open(output_file, 'w') as output:
        process = subprocess.Popen(['java', java_file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

        for line in inputs:
            process.stdin.write(line)
            process.stdin.flush()

        out, err = process.communicate()
        output.write(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_java_with_input(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

Comment: Hey, can u try adding a '\n' such that it becomes process.stdin.write(line + '\n')  , to simulate the Enter key press after each guess. If possible add ur java pgm to, it wud help to debug.